# How to trigger view auto layout adjustments after calling setFrame?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

Say I have to views with even widths. Left and right edges are aligned with 5 space vertically between them. If I call setFrame: on the top view to move it higher up in the superview, is the lower view supposed to move with it automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but if you're using autolayout for positioning the upper view, you shouldn't call setFrame. That will have no effect.
Instead, modify the constraint.
Create an outlet in your view controller referencing the constraint for the vertical space between the upper view and the top layout guide.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *verticalSpaceConstraint;
```

Then instead of setFrame, do:

```
verticalSpaceConstraint.constant = 10; // or whatever distance you want between the top of the screen and the upper view
```